# Dynamically connect Google Sheets to Excel with protection of privacy of information

Tags: google-sheets, import

I know of only one way to import information (live) to Excel from Google Sheets, but it requires "publish to the web" on that Google sheet, and adding a "connection" to Excel.

My concern with this is that there could be sensitive information that anyone who obtains a URL to the published Google sheet can have access to information that should remain private.

**Is there another way to connect Google Sheets to Excel?**
(Or) does one need to scramble the information on the published sheet (a la enigma machine + key) and decrypt it on the Excel side when receiving it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/), the [Google Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/) or a third party Excel plug-in.